# Salidas distintas ¿Porque?

Tags: c, dev-c++

Hola buenas estabamos hoy en clase y estabamos corrigiendo el examen que tuvimos el otro dia y un compañero se encontro con un error y me mando su codigo para ver si lo podía resolver o saber porque era. La cuestión es que nosotros en clase utilizamos el programa borland c++ y en el programa salia que la inversión mínima era tanto la inversión 1 como la inversión 17 cuando esta ultima no lo era (como se ve en la imagen).
Lo que hice fue copiar el código y ejecutarlo en dev c++ y esto salia correcto.

¿Porque puede ser? me gustaría saberlo para saciar mi curiosidad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la de la izquierda es la salida que proporciona borland y la de la derecha la que proporciona dev c++

Este es el codigo

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

main()
{int i;
float inv[16], invt=0, invm, invmax=0, invmin;
FILE *  PInv;
PInv = fopen("Inversiones.txt","w+");

for(i=0; i<=16; i=i+1)
{
   do
   {
        printf("Introduzca el valor de la inversion: ");
    scanf("%f", &inv[i]);
   }
    while((inv[i]<0));
}
//clrscr();

for(i=0; i<=16; i=i+1)
{
    invt = invt + inv[i];
}
printf("La inversion total es: %f", invt);
fprintf(PInv, "La inversion total es: %f", invt);

invm = invt/17;
printf("\n\rLa media total es: %f", invm);
fprintf(PInv, "\n\rLa media total es: %f", invm);

invmin= inv[0];

for(i=0; i<=16; i=i+1)
{
    if(inv[i]>=invmax)
   {
    invmax = inv[i];
   }

   if(inv[i]<=invmin)
   {
    invmin = inv[i];
   }
}

printf("\n\rLa inversion maxima es: %f", invmax);
printf("\n\rLa inversion minima es: %f", invmin);

fprintf(PInv, "\n\rLa inversion maxima es: %f", invmax);
fprintf(PInv, "\n\rLa inversion minima es: %f", invmin);

for(i=0; i<=16; i=i+1)
{
    if(inv[i]==invmax)
   {
    printf("\n\rLa inversion maxima es la %i inversion", i+1);
      fprintf(PInv, "\n\rLa inversion maxima es la %i inversion", i+1);
   }
}

for(i=0; i<=16; i=i+1)
{
   if(inv[i]==invmin)
   {
    printf("\n\rLa inversion minima es la %i inversion", i+1);
      fprintf(PInv, "\n\rLa inversion minima es la %i inversion", i+1);
   }
}

fclose(PInv);
Sleep(99999);
}
```

Comment: Tengo la bola de cristal en el taller, así que no puedo adivinar el código. ¿Podrías publicar el código para que le echemos un vistazo?

Comment: vale ahora lo paso jaja sry

Comment: el codigo tiene un error en el tamaño del arreglo, float inv[16] almacena 16 elementos entre los indices 0 y 15 inclusive. Si realizas una operacion sobre el indice 16 puede ocurrir cualquier cosa, dependiendo del SO o el compilador, muy problablemente crashee por un segmentation fault

Comment: A juzgar por la salida de la izquierda, parece que el último dato, aunque lo leyó correctamente como 17 (pues la suma total y la media salen iguales), después se cambió de alguna forma su valor y se puso a 1. Así el máximo queda en 16.0 y se entiende también que te diga que la inversión mínima es la 1 y la 17. ¿Puedes imprimir los elementos del array al final del programa para verificar que efectivamente el último elemento cambió su valor a 1?

Comment: si tienes razón cuando luego imprimes los elementos del array se cambia el ultimo cambio su valor a uno. muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dada la definicion siguiente:

```
float inv[16]
```

Al acceder a la posicion 16 de `inv` en los loops escritos como:

```
for(i=0; i<=16; i=i+1)
```

Estas acciendo fuera de los limites de la memoria declarada para esa variable, por lo que el resultado no está definido.

Muy problablemente ese mismo codigo usando distintos compiladores, sistemas operativos o maquinas se comporte distinto, por ejemplo:

- Accede a la memoria de otra variable del stack
- Accede a memoria de otro proceso

Dependiendo de esto puede crashiar el programa, o simplemente funcionar con un comportamiento erroneo.